# Найти значение примера

Tags: python

[image: Пример]

Результат не сходится, подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

```
u = ((8+math.fabs((-4.5-0.000075)**2)+1)**(1/3))/((-4.5**2)+(0.000075**2)+2)-math.exp(math.fabs(-4.5-0.000075))*((math.tan(math.degrees(84.5+1)**2))**(-4.5))
b=int(input("Введите точность вывода результата b ="))
def toFixed(numObj, digits=0):
    return f"{numObj:.{digits}f}"
u = toFixed(u,b)
print("у = ", u)
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать инициализированные переменные вместо констант

Comment: совет - запустите: `print(-1**2)` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [таблице приоритетов операций/операторов Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) (вверху - самые слабые, внизу - самые сильные операторы), унарный минус слабее операции возведения в степень:

```
                                   Operator                              Description
0                                    lambda                        Lambda expression
1                                 if – else                   Conditional expression
2                                        or                               Boolean OR
3                                       and                              Boolean AND
4                                     not x                              Boolean NOT
5   in, not in, is, is not, <, <=, >, >=...  Comparisons, including membership te...
6                                         |                               Bitwise OR
7                                         ^                              Bitwise XOR
8                                         &                              Bitwise AND
9                                    <<, >>                                   Shifts
10                                     +, -                 Addition and subtraction
11                           *, @, /, //, %  Multiplication, matrix multiplicatio...
12                               +x, -x, ~x          Positive, negative, bitwise NOT
13                                       **                         Exponentiation 6
14                                  await x                         Await expression
15  x[index], x[index:index], x(argument...  Subscription, slicing, call, attribu...
16  (expressions...), [expressions...], ...  Binding or tuple display, list displ...
```

Соответственно, некоторые операции дадут не тот результат, который вы ожидаете:

```
In [14]: print(-4.5**2)
-20.25
```